# InfoPath 2010 Radio Buttons bound to different fields

Tags: radio-button, infopath, infopath2010

I have about 18 radio buttons, each bound to their own field. They are all in the same section. However, a user is able to select more then one of these buttons. I want the user to only be able to select one of these buttons. I know this can be done if they are bound to the same element, but is there a way to do it if they are bound to separate elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to use either Rules (e.g. Condition: button2 = "1", Rule Type: Action, Run these actions: Set a field's value: . = "0"), or write custom code in a code-behind project.

Given the amount of buttons involved, I would recommend using custom code (C# or Visual Basic), since you're going to have to setup a **lot** of rules to manage it all, and it will get very unwieldy, very quickly.

Comment: Sadly, that's pretty much what I thought I was going to have to do. Stupid InfoPath ...

Comment: Yeah, I've been down this road before. Although, I gotta say once you get the hang of doing code-behind, you really discover the true power of InfoPath.